# exporting of .Rmd file in Emacs polymode does not work

Tags: emacs, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to export the file `template.Rmd`, available [here](http://www.jacolienvanrij.com/Tutorials/template.Rmd), to pdf, using polymode in Emacs. I choose the Rmarkdown-ESS exporter. Upon pressing `M-n e` and selecting pdf as output format, the weaving appears to go all right, yet the Pandoc call throws up the following error message:

`! Package pdftex.def Error: File "/path/template{[}exported{]}_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf" not found.` (with simple instead of double inverted commas.)

Indeed, I can find no such file anywhere near the working directory.

One of the arguments of the command `rmarkdown::render()`, executed by `M-n e` is `output_file = "/path/template[exported].pdf"` (with simple inverted commas again). When I modify that to read `output_file = "/path/template.pdf"` everything works fine.

So the problem appears to be the default naming of the output file by polymode. How can this be changed? Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this [.el file](https://github.com/polymode/polymode/blob/master/polymode-export.el), this can be changed by adding:

```
(defcustom polymode-exporter-output-file-format "%s"
  "Format of the exported files.
%s is substituted with the current file name sans extension."
  :group 'polymode-export
  :type 'string)
```

to the init file.

By default, it seems that `%s` is replaced by `%s[exported]` where `%s` is the name of the file to be exported.

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks. Vitalie Spinu, the developer of Polymode, wrote that the problem lied with Pandoc, which apparently does not recognise `[]` in file names correctly. Vitalie changed the output format to `"%s-exported"`, and this works fine for me.